# Exception: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Services.Term' to 'bool'

Tags: c#, ms-solver-foundation

I'm getting an exception

> "Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Services.Term' to 'bool'"

in the following code:

```
double T1;
Decision T4;

var XX3 = T1 > (T4 - 0.001) ? T4 - 0.001 : T1;
```

How it is possible to fix this problem?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SolverFoundation. Decision is a class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.services.decision(v=vs.93).aspx

Comment: You're hiding something. In your code I can't see where is `Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Services.Term` used?

Comment: @SonerGönül: I don't think that's the problem, as it says it cannot convert to "bool" not to "double". The only bool thing here is the left hand side of the ? operator, which compares doubles here.

Comment: I have a method: public static Term SKPK(double T1, Decision T4) {var XX3 = T1 > (T4 - 0.001) ? T4 - 0.001 : T1; ......}

Comment: @SriramSakthivel [`Decision`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.services.decision.aspx) derives from `Term`. What he didn't show was the namespace `Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Services`, but it is in the error text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use overloads of [subtraction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.services.term.op_subtraction.aspx) and [greater than](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.services.term.op_greaterthan.aspx) that have a return type `Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Services.Term` (see links). Then you use that expression `x` as the first part (of three) in the conditional operator `x ? a : b`. But a `bool` is required there.

---

I suggest you use **[`Model.If`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.services.model.if.aspx)** instead, it appears to be Solver Foundation's "conditional operator". To be technical, the C# language does not allow overloading the `?:` ternary operator the way many binary operators like `-` and `>` can be overloaded.

So change:

```
var XX3 = T1 > (T4 - 0.001) /* illegal! */ ? T4 - 0.001 : T1;
```

into:

```
var XX3 = Model.If(T1 > T4 - 0.001, T4 - 0.001, T1);
```

Disclaimer: I am not a Solver Foundation user.

Comment: How can I convert it to bool?

Comment: @user3362850 I expanded my answer with a suggestion.